# Unit testing with enzyme got Cannot read property 'be' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

My not working test

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';
import TopNav from '../components/topNav';

it('Navbar should existed', () => {
    const nav = shallow(<TopNav />);
    expect(nav.find('#topNav').exists()).to.be(true);
});
```

My topNav Component.

```
import { Component } from 'react';

export default class topNav extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div id="topNav"><strong className="testtest">Nav bar</strong></div>
        )
    }
}
```

I have no clue what is wrong here. I took the exact example from the API doc of enzyme. But when I do this, it worked

```
it('Navbar should existed', () => {
    expect(shallow(<TopNav />).is('#topNav')).toBe(true);
});
```

This is what the doc says 
http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/exists.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Jasmine or Chai? You say that

> ```
> it('Navbar should existed', () => {
>     expect(shallow(<TopNav />).is('#topNav')).toBe(true);
> });
> ```

works, and `.toBe` is a Jasmine `expect` assertion function. And the equivalent for Chai (which I think you're not using) is `to.be`. This is why `to` is undefined for you. Change your `to.be` to `toBe`, and it should work.

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow, mount} from 'enzyme';
import TopNav from '../components/topNav';

it('Navbar should existed', () => {
    const nav = shallow(<TopNav />);
    expect(nav.find('#topNav').exists()).toBe(true);
});
```

Comment: I'm not using jasmine or chai, I'm using jest with enzyme

Comment: I see. I just looked at Jest docs, and `toBe` is also the assertion function (like Jasmine) and not `to.be`. Can you try that and report back?

Comment: Jest claim to be used smoothly with enzyme, I'm using enzyme with jest, look at this http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/exists.html

Comment: It definitely can be used smoothly with enzyme but I think you misunderstood what I was trying to say. The examples, as well as your test as it stand right now is written with the 'to' assertion rather than toBe that Jest uses. Note from the enzyme docs that it uses mocha/chai syntax: "The documentation and examples for enzyme use mocha and chai, but you should be able to extrapolate to your framework of choice."

Comment: Take a look at the jest docs and note that it uses toBe and not to.be https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/using-matchers.html

Comment: I got it now, thanks for the clarification. if that's the case where is enzyme being used?

Comment: Enzyme is used for mounting/traversing and manipulating the react components, so it's usefulness is specific to react. However testing runners and assertion libraries like Mocha/Chai, Jasmine, and Jest handle the actual assertions in most any JavaScript environment/framework

Comment: I got it now, but there's still bunch of overlap stuff btw jest and enzyme. For example jest has mock, and enzyme still can be used with sinon, isn't that redundant?

Comment: Well sinon is a separate npm module, and I think you'll find that when different organizations release products, sometimes their featuresets overlap, its just the nature of the eco-system. I wouldn't worry too much about that and just find/use the tools you feel the most comfortable with.